# Encode a base64 request body into a binary

Tags: go

I'm fairly new to the Go language and having a hard time achieving the following: I'm receiving a base64 string (basically, an encoded image) and need to transform it to the binary form on the server.

```
func addOrUpdateUserBase64(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params martini.Params) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    sDec, _ := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(r.Body)
...
```

This is not working, because DecodeString expects a string... how do I transform request.Body into a string? Any tips are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString`, instead set up a decoder directly from the `r.Body`

```
dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, r.Body)`  // dec is an io.Reader
```

now use `dec`, e.g. dump to a `bytes.Buffer` like

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
n, err := io.copy(buf, dec)
```

which will decode `r.Body` into buf or copy directly to a http.Response or a file.

Or use Peter's method below if keeping all in memory is okay.

Comment: I think this is the right way to do it. I would use `new(bytes.Buffer) ` just for style ;)

Comment: Wow! This is pure Go awesomeness. Can you recommend any further reading dealing specifically with io.Readers / Writers and their use across Go?

Comment: [this](http://blog.golang.org/gif-decoder-exercise-in-go-interfaces) and [this](http://blog.golang.org/json-rpc-tale-of-interfaces) and the beginning section of [this](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) and [this](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types).

Answer (score 1):

> [func (*Encoding) Decode](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.Decode)
>
> ```
> func (enc *Encoding) Decode(dst, src []byte) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Decode decodes src using the encoding enc. It writes at most
>   DecodedLen(len(src)) bytes to dst and returns the number of bytes
>   written. If src contains invalid base64 data, it will return the
>   number of bytes successfully written and CorruptInputError. New line
>   characters (\r and \n) are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

And one more option would be just casting `r.Body` to a `string` :

//Edit, fixed the code to work with an io.Reader

```
import "io/ioutil"
..........
if body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); err == nil {
       sDec, _ := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(body))
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that, I thought it was []byte.

Comment: @Volker I have done the same :)